# Hibernate Envers how to get revision by property of EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I need to get revision by property of EmbeddedId. But I dont know how.

```
@Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "orders_details")
@Audited
public class OrderDetail implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderDetailsId id;


@Embeddable
public class OrderDetailsId implements Serializable {


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String prodName;

    @Basic
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
        List list = auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Order.class, false, false).
                add(AuditEntity.property("id.order").eq(id)).getResultList();
```

GetResultList throw NullPointer (. 
How i can do it?

Ok) Here Stack Trace

```
> 2017-03-08 11:48:00.548 ERROR 4548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]   
   >     o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for   
   >     servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception 
   >     [Request processing failed; nested exception is   
   >     java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
   >            java.lang.NullPointerException: null    at    org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntitiesConfigurations.getRelationDescription(EntitiesConfigurations.java:98)
   >     ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at   
   >     org.hibernate.envers.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaTools.getRelatedEntity(CriteriaTools.java:44)
   >     ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at   
   >     org.hibernate.envers.query.criteria.internal.SimpleAuditExpression.addToQuery(SimpleAuditExpression.java:45)
   >     ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at   
   >     org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:89)
   >     ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at   
   >     org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:93)
   >     ~[hibernate-envers-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]  at   
   >     com.spring.dao.impl.OrderDetailsDAOImpl.getRevision(OrderDetailsDAOImpl.java:52)
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     com.spring.dao.impl.OrderDetailsDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$38c0db60.invoke()
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
   >     ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
   >     ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     com.spring.dao.impl.OrderDetailsDAOImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6146d8cb.getRevision()
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     com.spring.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.getOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:78)
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     com.spring.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7d1c6228.invoke()
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
   >     ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
   >     ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
   >     ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
   >     ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
   >     ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     com.spring.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d51254c.getOrder()
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     com.spring.web.WaitersController.getOrderDetails(WaitersController.java:61)
   >     ~[classes/:na]     at   
   >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
   >     ~[na:1.8.0_111]    at   
   >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   >     ~[na:1.8.0_111]    at   
   >     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   >     ~[na:1.8.0_111]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   >     ~[na:1.8.0_111]    at   
   >     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)   
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
   >     ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]   at   
   >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)   
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]    at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
   >     ~[spring-security-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
   >     ~[spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
   >     ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]     at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   >     [na:1.8.0_111]     at   
   >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   >     [na:1.8.0_111]     at   
   >     org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   >     [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]  at   
   >     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
```

Comment: can you drop complete stack trace it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because you are asking the Envers Query API to locate revisions for the `Order` entity, which you did not specify as as being *audited*.

I have filed a JIRA issue [HHH-11558](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11558) to address this problem with a more meaingful response.

Had `Order` been *audited*, it would have worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still did not understand what to do. I can not edit the nested key anymore, since too much is tied to it. But I can not understand one thing, why the audit table has this field but I can not directly address it.
And maybe it's all a can rework with using RevisionEntity?

Comment: I have modified the answer @ЮлийЩербак.  What you actually were trying would have worked so long as `Order` had been audited.  Sorry for the confusion, I had a mistake in my test case I wrote for it.

Comment: Thanks @Naros. It really helped. And thank you for taking the time for me.